# How to use 'awk' to determine the maximal value in multiple subsets of data within a file?

Tags: awk

Good morning,

I am using `awk` and trying to determine the max value of multiple sets of data within a file. Let's say I have the data:

```
    1 2 3
  4 5 6 7 8
  9 8 7 6 5
    4 3 2
    1 2 3
  4 6 7 8 7
  7 8 7 6 5
    4 3 2
```

I would like the output to be:

```
9
8
```

As every four lines is a subset of data, and 9 is the max value of the first set, and 8 is the max value of the second. I'm piping the above data in the first code block to:

```
awk 'NR%4<4 || NR==4 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>maxval) maxval=$i;}; END { print maxval;}' > file
```

But it only returns the max value of the whole file:

```
9
```

I was wondering if it is possible to print a max value of every n lines (n=4 here) in one awk command, or do I need to break it up? I had thought the NR%4<4 || NR==4 would tell the rest of the function to execute on every four lines, but seems like it's looking at all the data and only determining one 'maxval'.

Thanks.

Comment: I would break it up into two, one to run on `NR%4==0` and one to run on `(NR+1)%4==0`.  You'll also need to have two variables to track the two values you're watching.

Comment: For every line, update the max value. If NR%4==0 then print out max value and reset it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>maxval) maxval=$i;}
     NR%4==0 { print maxval ; maxval= -1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, using an array.

```
awk '{x=split($0,a);asort(a);if(a[x]>maxval)maxval=a[x]}
     NR%4==0 { print maxval ; maxval= -1}'
```

Comment: Thank you, tried applying this, received an error message about the wrong number of arguments to function "asort", didn't seem to like (NR=1)

Comment: Odd, I'm on `GNU Awk 3.1.7`, maybe some compatibility issue.

Comment: Probably, I've had similar issues with simple things in 'sed'. Appreciate it though.

Comment: @Cbhihe - I expect Henry has moved on to other problems in the (almost) 3 intervening years ;-)